# Can you combine photons to ionise electrons?

Tags: energy, spectroscopy, atoms, ionization-energy

I was talking with a friend about the photoelectric effect. I know that only light of a certain energy will eject an electron from a metal plate.

But consider this.

A photon (red) had the exact energy such that it could be excite an electron to a higher energy state, *but* not enough for ionisation.

Then another photon (blue) tag teams with it, whilst the electron is in the higher energy state. Now with the new energy, it could be ionised.

[image]

Is this possible? If not (which is my suspicion), why not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but not very probable. See this [answer of mine.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709635/photoelectric-emission-at-frequency-less-then-threshold-frequency/709638#709638)

Not all atoms will be excited with the first photon, and the probability of the photon to fall on the excited atoms is much less than the direct photoelectric effect.